# How to time a program in my script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm writing this script where I have to run a program, time it and write that time into a text file, it must be in seconds with 6 decimal places. So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_THREADS=8   #2 x number of cores

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then                  #checks number of arguments
    echo Invalid number of arguments
    exit 1
else
    NUM_THREADS=$1
fi

if [ $NUM_THREADS -gt $MAX_THREADS ]; then     
    echo Invalid number of threads
    exit 1
fi    

make clean
make
start=$(date +%s)
./CircuitRouter-SeqSolver $2
end=$(date +%s)

 cat > $2.speedup.csv << EOF
 $((end-start))
 EOF
```

You can ignore anything related to NUM_THREADS that's for another part of the script. So I make clean, make and then run CircuitRouter-SeqSolver with $2 as an argument, I saw this solution with date but it only writes the number of seconds without decimal numbers so it just writes 0 into the file since the program takes less than 1 second to finish. How can I modify date to write decimal numbers?

Comment: You could run your sample code, say, 100 times, and divide the total duration by 100 to get a better idea of the time taken.

Comment: I'll "leave open" precision might have change in last 7 years.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `date` is the GNU version:

```
start=$(date +%s.%N)
./CircuitRouter-SeqSolver $2
end=$(date +%s.%N)
```

Other versions may or may not have `%N` nanosecond part. To limit the resolution to six decimal places you could do various things, but easiest is likely:

```
printf "%0.6f\n" $((end-start))
```

Edit: fix for `bash` doesn't do floating point math:

```
printf %0.6f\n" $(echo $end-$start | bc)
```

Comment: What version of bash supports math with decimals (non-integers) in ``$((…))``?

Comment: Haha. Good question. I don't know. I use `ksh` and it just worked, and I thought `bash` would too. Absent that being portable, I'd use `bc`: `duration=$(echo 1.0123456789 - 0.123456789 | bc)`

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol But won't this print in nanoseconds? Also, how do I print just the value to the file?

Comment: You use the printf to round to the detail you want and you use regular shell redirects to print to a file. Judging from your use of a here-doc it seems you know how to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Did you have a look at my `bosh` package from http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html?
It is the current maintained version of the Bourne Shell.

It supports to do timing with microsecond accuracy, see man the page http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html in the parameter section (around page 25) there is the description for the variable `TIMEFORMAT`.

Note that the accuracy for System CPU time and User CPU time on Linux is only 1 ms, but the wall clock time can be retrieved with microsecond accuracy.

You need to know that the output of the `time` builtin or automated timing for every command goes to `stderr` of the main shell and that you may need to redirect `stderr` for the command separately to be able to fetch the related output in a separate file.